# Android: simplest way to RECEIVE data from server?

Tags: android

I am creating an app that needs to be able to receive data at any time, without sending a request first. I could easily have the app send frequent requests to ask if there is an update, but I assume that would be battery-intensive. What is the simplest way I can have my server send data to my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called push-notifications. There are several solutions for this. One of them is [Google's C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html). Another example is [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/).

But note that push notifications are designed to only signal about the fact that new data is available. The actual data should be retrieved by client separately.

Comment: That sounds perfect, I'll sign up for the lab